# Does a C function without any argument and return value require a stack to execute?

Tags: c, stack

Does below function need any stack for execution?

```
int a;
void func(void)
{
    a = 10;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the compiler/settings. I would say it will just get inlined, so no stack would be required.

Comment: C does not know about the stack.

Comment: The main reason why this might not require a stack is that it has no local variables and calls no functions in non-tail position (nor anywhere else).

Comment: _If_ it's a stack based architecture, you need at least some stack space for the return address.

Comment: Only `-O0` setting is generating a call and not inlining on the [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zRsK-K) with GCC v8.2. Any other `-O` setting is inlining. So again - depends.

Comment: @machine_1: The question asks about a stack, not the stack. C semantics in fact define a stack: In computer science, a data structure with last-in first-out operations is a stack, and C’s function-call semantics define such behavior. You can implement this in software without some hardware-defined stack, but the implementation is nonetheless a stack, within implementation limits. Then the question of whether the function in the question can be implemented without using stack space is reasonable.

Comment: Without specific information about platform, compiler and compiler arguments there is no way to answer this question. Nothing in the C standard can answer this - it all depends on the implementation used.

Comment: @4386427: Yes, this question can be answered. It does not ask whether a compiler **will** use stack space. It asks whether a C implementation **needs** stack space to implement the function. We know there exist implementations that do not use stack space when implementing this function, and therefore the answer is, no, it is not **needed**.

Answer (score 2):

As long as a C compiler can see the definition of `func`, it can<sup>1</sup> implement `func` without using any stack space. For example, where it sees a call to `func`, it can implement that by emitting an instruction or two to move 10 into `a`. That would achieve the same result as calling `func` as a subroutine, so the C rules permit a C implementation to implement a call to `func` in that way, and it does not use any stack space.

Generally, if the compiler could not see the definition of `func`, as when compiling another source file that calls `func` but does not define it, the compiler would have to issue a call instruction or something similar, and that would, at the least, push the return address onto the stack.

Additionally, if the routine being called were more complicated, the compiler might choose not to implement it inline or might not be able to do so. (For example, if `func` contained calls to itself, it is generally not possible for the compiler to implement it with inline code in all situations; the compiler will need to implement it with actual subroutine call instructions, which do use stack space.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Whether any particular compiler will implement `func` without using stack space is another matter, dependent on the compiler, the switches used to compile, and other factors.

Comment: I think another consideration the compiler might take in account is how often this function is called from different places in the code